# Processing data of multiple dropdownmenus in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

So the problem is pretty simple. If i choose one option of the dropdownmenus, it get processed immediatly. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBKIK.png)

In my case i want it to wait until i press the confirmbutton so it can process all data immediatly.

This is my testcode so far:

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Define three dropdown menus
        self.dropdown1 = discord.ui.Select(placeholder='Select option 1', options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label='Option 1', value='option1'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Option 2', value='option2')
        ])
        self.add_item(self.dropdown1)

        self.dropdown2 = discord.ui.Select(placeholder='Select option 2', options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label='Option A', value='optiona'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Option B', value='optionb')
        ])
        self.add_item(self.dropdown2)

        self.dropdown3 = discord.ui.Select(placeholder='Select option 3', options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label='Choice X', value='choicex'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='Choice Y', value='choicey')
        ])
        self.add_item(self.dropdown3)      

    @discord.ui.button(label="Confirm", custom_id="Confirmbutton")
    async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{self.dropdown1.values[0]} | {self.dropdown2.values[0]} | {self.dropdown3.values[0]}")
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Every component when activated, be it a button, a dropdown or a modal, will produce an interaction that needs to be responded to by your bot. Only after the response will Discord know that everything went well. My suggestion is that you create your dropdowns using `@discord.ui.select(...)` and respond to interactions by editing the message.